# Oracle apex - disable notification on modal page from page 0

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

On global page (page 0) I have content for global notification. But when open modal page over standard page I have double notification top of page in background and top of modal page.

Is it possible disable notification on modal page only appear on standard oracle apex page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how to do it for *modal pages* (as "page type"), but - see if the following suggestion helps.

As objects on page 0 affect all pages, set notification's **Server side condition** not to display on certain page numbers. For example, if you don't want to see it on pages 26, 42 and 73, server side condition (whose type is "Function body") would look like this:

```
RETURN :APP_PAGE_ID not in (26, 42, 73);
```

Basically, you'd put all those modal pages' numbers in here.

---

As of comment posted by user_odoo: that might be possible, nice idea as well; see

```
SELECT *
  FROM apex_application_pages
 WHERE     application_id = :APP_ID
       AND page_mode = 'Modal Dialog';
```

Function body would then look like this:

```
DECLARE
   l_cnt  NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT (*)
     INTO l_cnt
     FROM apex_application_pages
    WHERE     application_id = :APP_ID
          AND page_id = :APP_PAGE_ID
          AND page_mode = 'Modal Dialog';

   RETURN l_cnt = 0;
END;
```

Comment: Nice idea,  Is it possible with query get all modal page ID from my app?   Or maybe  use some like this  RETURN :APP_PAGE_ID not in (Select page_id from my_app where type = 'MODAL');

Comment: I believe so, @user_odoo, thank you for the idea. You'd query APEX_APPLICATION_PAGES and filter on PAGE_MODE column.

Comment: @Littlefoot  Nice!

Comment: I'm glad if it helped, Pointer :)